# how common is gettext on webservers?

Tags: php, webserver, gettext

Working on a multi-lingual long term Project, which is intended to run on any possible web server, i relied on [this gettext-emulation](https://launchpad.net/php-gettext/) and my own localization files.

Now, since this emulation is quite outdated (and generate a lot of "deprecated"-messages on php 7.3), i would like to switch to either the native gettext module or a more current emulation. And to clarify that:  Since there is practically no chance of translation consistency all over the world, especially when it comes to context, i will still go with my own PO files (and localization environment) and just use the functionality, provided with gettext.

My websearch about gettext emulations brings up nothing usable, which lets me think native gettext-support may be good enough to go with. But still, since gettext is a php module, and possibly is not been installed on a server...:

how common is gettext on web servers? And how common is it enabled?

Since my web search to this question also leads nowhere, is there any knowledge or ressource out there, telling how safe it is these days, to rely on the native gettext module on web servers.

Sidequestion: are there any modern gettex-emulations out there?

Comment: There are several issues with `gettext` in my experience - from the basic fact that it's practically impossible to get it working on Windows machines (so you potentially end up with additional variance between your dev and live environments) to the fact that it doesn't work brilliantly with short strings that may have different translations based on context (e.g. `'sale','uitverkoop'` in the PO file - even if `uitverkoop` is not necessarily the correct term in all contexts)... not to mention the fact you need to reload Apache every time you change the PO file. Personally, I'd avoid it.

Comment: @CD001 Your concerns are absolutely understandable, and are also my concerns (and was also in the past). I assume there is practically no chance of translation consistency all over the world, especially when it comes to context. Therefore i will still go with my own PO files (and localization environment) and just use the functionality, provided with gettext. This works quite well so far. I will clarify that in the question.

Comment: @SirDarki has your method worked well for you? Any issues? (using Gettext and your own PO files)